# JTable duplicate entry

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

How can I prevent duplication of data in JTable?
The for loop determines whether the data contains similar ID.
Yes, it determines and show a JOptionPane which works.
But my problem is that it scans for a duplicate after I setValue on table 2.
I want my program to prevent duplication of data before it setValue on table 2.

```
public void dProductList(){
    table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            if(e.getClickCount() == 1) {
                JTable tbl = (JTable)e.getSource();
                int rrow = tbl.getSelectedRow();
                if(rrow>=0) {
                    int dcol = 0;
                    int rcol = 0;
                    ((DefaultTableModel)table2.getModel()).addRow(new Object[] {0,0,0,0});

                    while(rcol<table2.getColumnCount()-1) {

                                table2.setValueAt(table.getValueAt(rrow,rcol),drow,dcol);
                                totalAmount = totalAmount + (int) table2.getValueAt(drow,3);
                                rcol++;
                                dcol++;
                                if(rcol==table2.getColumnCount()-1) {
                                drow++;
                                }
                                label.setText(String.valueOf(totalAmount));         

                    }
                    for(int i=0; i<table2.getRowCount()-1;i++){     
                        if(table2.getValueAt(i,0).equals(table2.getValueAt(table2.getRowCount()-1,0))){

                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"item already listed");
                        }       
                    }


                        }


                }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `for loop` checking just before `table2.setValueAt` and add only if no duplicate.

You could also keep your data to a Set (eg a HashSet) and check there before adding to your JTable.